# 'shasum' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: ubuntu

I just downloaded Ubuntu OS and was verifying the download as per the website description using Windows Command Prompt.

The prompt then gives this below message:

```
'shasum' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or  batch file
```

Instructions from Ubuntu website,https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=20.04.1&architecture=amd64

Answer (score -1):

I ran the same command on git-bash and got the verification result.